# Generate + group new invoice line based on user date

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, list

My scenario is the following:

A user is assigned to one or more invoice item groups (that have a detail: the name of the user).

An itemgroup (= InvoiceLine) has:

- ID
- Name
- Quantity
- Cost
- Setup cost

itemgroupDetail (=InvoiceLineDetail) has:

- ID
- ItemgroupID
- Username

My **quantity is however based on the amount of users.**

Example:

User A, Joined at November 2018, is in the list 'Group G1'.

User A, Joined at November 2018 is in the list 'Group G2'.

User B, Joined at November 2018 is in the list 'Group G3'.

User B, Joined at March 2018 is in the list 'Group G1'.

User C, Joined at March 2018 is in the list 'Group G3'

What needs to be invoiced? 
All item groups. But if a user is joined in the month of invoicing, the group itself also needs to be a separate invoice line (since new users need to be invoiced once with the setup cost of which group he's in).

My invoicelines (result) needs to look  like

```
Quantity    Itemgroup   
    2       G1
    1       G2
    2       G3
    1       G1 NEW
    1       G2 NEW
    1       G3 NEW
```

My problem is that I do not know how I should tackle the fact that I dynamically need to create new invoicelines (with new details).

This is the code that I know have:

I start with creating invoice lines (but I do NOT set the quantity YET):

```
 public List<Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line> getInvoiceLines(int invoiceID)
        {
            List<Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line> lines = new List<Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line>();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM ITEMGROUPS", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add("@invoiceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = invoiceID;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line line = new Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line();
                line.invoiceID = invoiceID;
                line.itemgroupID = int.Parse(reader["id"].ToString());
                line.unitPrice = decimal.Parse(reader["price"].ToString());
                line.description = reader["name"].ToString();
                lines.Add(line);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return lines;
        }
```

Hereafter, for each invoice line, I go over the users + set the quantity of the invoice line and store the detail to the invoice line:

```
public Company_Invoice getInvoiceLineDetails(Company_Recurring_Invoice invoice)
        {
            Company_Recurring_Invoice i = invoice;

            foreach (Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line line in i.InvoiceLines)
            {
                getInvoiceLineDetails(line);
            }
            return i;
        }

public Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line getInvoiceLineLineDetails(Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line _line)
        {
            Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line Line = _line;
            Line.InvoiceLineDetails = new List<Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line_Detail>();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE ITEMGROUPID = @ITEMGROUP", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ITEMGROUP", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Line.itemgroupID;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
// We create a new detail line (with the name of the user + check it's date) 
//THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO CHECK IF THE MONTH OF THE USER = MONTH OF INVOICING AND ADD IT TO AN EXISTING OR NEW INVOICE LINE TOO 
            DateTime Date = DateTime.Parse(reader["joindate"].ToString());

                    Line.quantity++;
                    Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line_Detail detail = new Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line_Detail();
                detail.Value = reader["name"].ToString();
                detail.Company_Recurring_Invoice_Line = Line.InvoiceLineID;
                Line.InvoiceLineDetails.Add(detail);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return Line;
        }
```

My code works perfectly for users that aren't new (my lines + details are generated perfectly) but i'm scratching my head to find out how I could implement the fact that it also needs to create a separate invoice line IF the date of the user is for example 11. Keep in mind that the NEW invoice lines are also needed to be populated by more than one user.

What would be the best way to implement this? Since optimizing is not really important here, I have been thinking about just creating separate methods for this or new classes (first generate old ones, and then create new ones) but could I do it without doing that?